# Tableviewer refresh() does not work. Only shows data after resizing window

Tags: refresh, jface, tableviewer

A 2-sash sashform. A 3-level `TreeViewer` in one and a `TableViewer` in the other. When it starts no item is selected in the `TreeViewer`
and the `TableViewer` shows a list of all the first level objects available. To achieve this, the `TreeViewerContainer` instantiates the `TableViewerContainer` and then calls its `showFirstLevelItemList( )` method :

```
public class TableViewerContainer {
private Table table;
private TableViewer tableViewer;
private TableColumnLayout layout;

public TableViewerContainer(SashForm sashForm) {

    Composite composite = new Composite(sashForm, SWT.NONE);
    composite.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, false));      
    tableViewer = new TableViewer(composite, SWT.BORDER
            | SWT.FULL_SELECTION);
    table = tableViewer.getTable();
    table.setHeaderVisible(true);
    table.setLinesVisible(true);

    // Add TableColumnLayout
    layout = new TableColumnLayout();
    composite.setLayout(layout);
}

public void showFirstLevelItemList( FirstLevelItemListContainer obj ) {
    // Add the only column
    TableViewerColumn tableViewerColumn = new TableViewerColumn(
            tableViewer, SWT.NONE);
    TableColumn tblclmnFirst = tableViewerColumn.getColumn();

    layout.setColumnData(tblclmnFirst, new ColumnWeightData(10,
            ColumnWeightData.MINIMUM_WIDTH, false));

    tblclmnFirst.setText("Description");

    // assign providers and show the table 
    tableViewer.setLabelProvider(new FirstLevelItemLabelProvider());
    tableViewer.setContentProvider(new FirstLevelItemContentProvider());
    tableViewer.setInput(obj);      
}
```

This works fine.

Next,  selecting an item in the `TreeViewer` causes the tableViewer to update the data accordingly. To effect this I added a `SelectionChangedListener()`:

```
treeViewer.addSelectionChangedListener(new ISelectionChangedListener() {
        public void selectionChanged(SelectionChangedEvent event) {
            IStructuredSelection selection = (IStructuredSelection) event
                    .getSelection();
            Object obj = selection.getFirstElement();
            if (obj instanceof firsLevelDetail ) {  
                FirstLevelDetail fld = (FirstLevelDetail) obj;
                tableViewer.showFirstLevelDetail(fld);               

            } else if (obj instanceof SecondLevelDetail )
                SecondLevelDetail sld = (SecondLevelDetail) obj;
                tableViewer.showSecondLevelDetail(sld);              

            else if (obj instanceof ThirdLevelDetail)
            ThirdLevelDetail tld = (ThirdLevelDetail) obj;
                tableViewer.showSecondLevelDetail(tld);
        }
    });`
```

So that when the user selects a `firstLevelItem` the `TableViewer` shows the corresponding data. All the methods called follow the following pattern :

```
private void showFirstLevelDetail( FirstLevelDetailObj obj ) {

    Table tbl = tableViewer.getTable();
    tbl.setRedraw(false);

    // Dispose former columns 
    while (tbl.getColumnCount() > 0) {
        tbl.getColumns()[0].dispose();
    }

    // add new columns  
    TableViewerColumn tableViewerColumn = new TableViewerColumn(
            tableViewer, SWT.NONE);
    TableColumn tblclmn = tableViewerColumn.getColumn();
    layout.setColumnData(tblclmn, new ColumnWeightData(1,
            ColumnWeightData.MINIMUM_WIDTH, true));
    tblclmn.setText("Code FL Item");

    tableViewerColumn = new TableViewerColumn(tableViewer, SWT.NONE);
    tblclmn = tableViewerColumn.getColumn();
    layout.setColumnData(tblclmn, new ColumnWeightData(1,
            ColumnWeightData.MINIMUM_WIDTH, true));
    tblclmn.setText("Description FL Item");

    tbl.setRedraw(true);

    // to avoid an Exception 
    tableViewer.setInput(null);

    // Assign new providers and show the data
    tableViewer.setLabelProvider(new FirstLevelDetailLabelProvider());
    tableViewer.setContentProvider(new FirstLevelDetailContentProvider());
    tableViewer.setInput(obj);
}
```

The ContentProviders' `getElements()` methods follow the next patern:

```
public Object[] getElements(Object inputElement) {
return ((FirstLevelDetail)inputElement).getArrayItems();                
}
```

My problem is after this process the table doesn't show a header or any data until it is resized. Then it works normally until another item is selected, no matter what level the item is.

`tableViewer.refresh()` does not work.
`tableViewer.getTable().redraw()` does not work.

All the `showXxxxLevelDetail ()` work properly if they are called in the first place, instead of  `showFirstLevelItemList()` method, provided `tableViewer.setInput(null)` is commented out.

I'm running Eclipse Indigo, jface 3.8, Windows XP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try to call

```
composite.layout();
```

after calling any of those showXXXLevelDetail() methods.

Comment: Yes! You nail it Behnil. Thank you very much!